# Will using selectors to compute derived data from an API call perform better than doing within the reducer? (for this use-case)

Tags: redux, immutable.js, reselect, redux-reducers

Say I have a music store app where the user searches for guitars. On initial page load, I fetch a few varieties of guitars to display: (acoustic, electric, and bass). Pages of guitar results are returned together from a single API call but will never be displayed together. Therefore, they must be filtered at some point. To view different categories of guitars, the user will toggle the category they view from a react component.

There seems to be two major ways I can approach this problem with immutable and redux.

In Strategy 1, I filter the data on category when it arrives, and store it separately in the redux store. When I want to retrieve the data, I specify the category in the selector.

In Strategy 2, all API data that comes in is stored in an aggregate List "all". When I want to retrieve a particular category of guitars, I used a selector to filter and display from the aggregated data.

STRATEGY 1:

```
// REDUCER
export const GuitarReducer = (state, action) => {
    const { payload, type } = state; 

    switch (type) {
        case "acoustic": {
            let existing = // GET EXISTING
            return state.set("acoustic",
                existing.concat(payload.filter(result => (result.category === "acoustic")))
            )
        }
        case "electric": {
            let existing = // GET EXISTING
            return state.set("electric",
                existing.concat(payload.filter(result => (result.category === "electric")))
            )    
        }
        case "bass": {
            let existing = // GET EXISTING
            return state.set("bass",
                existing.concat(payload.filter(result => (result.category === "bass")))
            )
        }
    }
}

// SELECTOR
export const selectCategory = createSelector(
    [getCategory, getGuitarReducer],
    (category, guitarReducer) => {
        return GuitarReducer.get(category);
    }
);
```

STRATEGY 2:

```
// REDUCER
export const GuitarReducer = (state, action) => {
    const { payload, type } = state;
    ...
    let existing = // GET EXISTING
    ...
    return state.set("all",
        existing.concat(payload)
    )
}

// SELECTOR
export const selectCategory = createSelector(
    [selectAllGuitars],
    (category, guitars) => {
        return guitars.filter(guitar => (guitar.category = category));
    }
);
```

Will one pattern give better performance than another? What pattern better follows best practices for redux?

I have heard that it is best to prefer selectors for computing derived data, and that memoization will cache the results to use when another action is performed on the data such as toggling between tabs. Because of this, it is not clear to me which strategy to prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `selectors` mainly focused of not re-computing derived data in your components (and the benefit of reusing it across other components).

Both in your example are good practices, so I would reframe it as follows. Do you want your datastore to look like in choice one or choice two (original API response). Do you want it to lazily load (choice two), or load categories for all guitars.

**Choice 1**

Pros

- Stores in datastore in format more useful to your application.
- Choice two recomputes on category change, choice one is computed at start and most likely more performant.

Cons

- No access to original API response.
- Performs filtering and categorizing on API request instead of lazily (Honestly not a big problem).

**Choice 2**

Pros

- Stores in datastore original API response.
- Lazily computes the required guitar category.

Cons

- Performs computation again on category change. (Note `reselect` only has a cache size of 1).
- Memoizing also takes additional memory.